# Is 'sum' an okay replacement for 'problem'?

Tags: word-usage, mathematics, subcontinental-english

I've seen some people using the word *sum* as a substitute for the word *problem*, in a mathematical context even though the problem does not explicitly involve the addition operation.

For example, *We discussed Huygen's Principle in the last class. I believe all of you checked out the sums related to that.*

Is this usage okay?

Comment: "The sums" in this context means "the computations / derivations" -- mathematical manipulations of some kind. e.g. I did the sums and it turns out that....  But it doesn't mean "problem" in a general sense.

Comment: Can you point to a dictionary definition that supports the interpretation of _sum_ that you want people to recognize as your intended meaning in the example you give? If so, please do.

Comment: I would consider it to be sloppy/anachronistic (in the US), if the equation was not limited to summation or integrals.  "Sum" was used in the sense of a general math problem 100 years ago, but not extensively in the past 50.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Shor pointed out, there are definitions of sum in the online Oxford Dictionary that do cover math problems not explicitly involving addition, so this is acceptable usage.

Comment: This is a British usage, so you need to look in a British dictionary to find it. For example, this usage is given [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sum) but not [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sum).

Comment: None of the definitions there pertain to academic problems that aren't mathematical or arithmetic in nature, though, unless I've missed something obvious?

Comment: The OP is asking about problems that are mathematical in nature, but don't look like 10385 + 3729 + 58392. Read the question more carefully.

Comment: Having looked more closely into what Huygen's Principle actually is, you're right. Mind if I edit my answer or would I be as well just deleting it?

Comment: Go ahead and edit it.

Comment: Is this usage still used in contemporary Britain?

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay Yes. 'Sums' as a synonym for 'Calculations' is still in use in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

*sum* may refer to the integral of something as well, seeing as when a curve is positive, the integral is the sum of infinitesimally slim squares below the curve adding up to the area below the curve.

While *sums* may indeed be used occasionally to refer to calculations in a broader sense, I should shy away from such usages: It dilutes the accuracy with which one might express oneself about mathematics.